# Zend_Navigation for displaying different menus in Layout

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework, zend-navigation

trying to print out about 3 menus on ZF. Currently I can't even get one out. Not quite sure what's going on and why theres no mention of how to get it working on the manual.

So this is my layout.phtml:

```
<body>
    <?php echo $this->layout()->nav; ?>
    <?php echo $this->layout()->content; ?>
</body>
```

Not entirely sure if this is how I'm meant to create the navigation but I plan on changing the routes eventually for localization:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <nav>
        <register>
            <label>Register</label>
            <controller>register</controller>
            <action>index</action>
        </register>
</nav>
</config>
```

I've got this in my bootstrap:

```
    protected function _initNavigation() 
{

    // Navigation
    $config = new Zend_Config_Xml(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/navigation.xml', 'nav');
    $container = new Zend_Navigation($config);

}
```

Only the content displays... Wanted to be able to have different menu types like... show(topMenu), show(loggedinSideMenu) sort of thing

Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things here...

First, to display navigation, use the appropriate helper. In your layout file...

```
<?php echo $this->navigation()->menu()
    ->renderMenu($zendNavigationContainer) ?>
```

See http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.navigation.introduction.html and http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.navigation

Secondly, `Zend_Application` has a [resource plugin for navigation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.available-resources.html#zend.application.available-resources.navigation) however it's only able to handle one container which doesn't really help you. I'd recommend something like this in your Bootstrap method...

```
protected function _initNavigation()
{
    // get config and create containers as before

    // bootstrap layout resource and retrieve it
    $this->bootstrap('layout');
    $layout = $this->getResource('layout');

    // add containers as layout properties
    $layout->topMenu = $topMenuContainer;
    $layout->loggedInSideMenu = $sideMenuContainer;
}
```

Then, in your layout

```
<!-- top menu -->
<?php echo $this->navigation()->menu()
    ->renderMenu($this->layout()->topMenu) ?>

<!-- side menu -->
<?php echo $this->navigation()->menu()
    ->renderMenu($this->layout()->loggedInSideMenu) ?>
```